# Application closing while leaving edit text

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have an application that contains several fragments in one activity.
And one of the fragment is implemented map with edit text for user address auto fill based on camera change listener, while i back press from that map fragment i manage to back to previous fragment, but once i clicked edit text in that map fragment pressing back button closing the full application without force close.
 I don't know the exact problem.
 Sorry for my bad English.

```
public class Maps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Unbinder unbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.address_submit)
    Button addressSubmit;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    IDU idu;
    User user;

    EditText addressDoor, addressAddressline, addressStreet, addressCity, addressPincode, addressState;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

        Activity_Dashboard.navigation.hideBottomNavigation();

        idu = new IDU_Presenter(this, getActivity());

        user = SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser();

        addressDoor = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.address_door);
        addressAddressline = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.address_addressline);
        addressStreet = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.address_street);
        addressCity = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.address_city);
        addressState = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.address_state);
        addressPincode = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.address_pincode);

        final RippleBackground rippleBackground = (RippleBackground) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content);
        ImageView b = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.confirm_address_map_custom_marker);

        rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        rootView.requestFocus();
        rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // Log.i(tag, "keyCode: " + keyCode);
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    Fragment_Address_list fragment = new Fragment_Address_list();
                    FragmentActivity activitys = (FragmentActivity) getActivity();
                    FragmentManager fm = activitys.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
                    ft.commit();

                    return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());

        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                double lat = mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
                double lng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;

                Location startPoint = new Location("locationA");
                startPoint.setLatitude(11.010519);
                startPoint.setLongitude(76.986481);
                Location startPoint1 = new Location("locationb");
                startPoint1.setLatitude(lat);
                startPoint1.setLongitude(lng);

                List<Address> addresses = null;

                try {

                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);

                    if (addresses.size() == 0) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                        if (addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() == null) {

                            addressAddressline.setText(addresses.get(0).getSubLocality());

                        } else {

                            addressAddressline.setText(addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare());

                        }

                        addressStreet.setText(addresses.get(0).getSubLocality());

                        addressCity.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                        addressPincode.setText(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode());
                        addressState.setText(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(11.010519, 76.986481);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint).title("Your location");
        Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMarker.showInfoWindow();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(TutorialsPoint, 18f));

    }
```

[image: Log details]

Comment: Can you post your code and the logs plz ?

Comment: Added the log picture

Comment: Post your code ! I cannot help you with just the logs ...

Comment: So if I understand your problem, you want to unselect the editText when the user click on the back button ? And this without closing the app ?

Comment: Yes, That also helps,

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onBackPressed()` method which is triggered when the user clicks on the back button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //DO YOUR STUFF LIKE SHOWING DIALOG
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MyActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

You can here change the fragment to go back to the previous one (which is the default behavior of your code as you are using fragmentManager), you can display a Toast or whatever.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Try to explain it correctly so I can help you.

Comment: When i open the map fragment  then pressing back button(without touching edit text) will back to previous fragment, but once i edited or touched the edit text in map fragment pressing back button closed the entire app

Comment: You can try this solution : https://medium.com/@Wingnut/onbackpressed-for-fragments-357b2bf1ce8e 
And don't forget to add `ft.addToBackStack(null);` before `ft.commit()` or the `popBackStack()` method won't do anything.